# Django dynamic page generation with templates

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, checkbox

I want to generate a page using templates and content blocks. The homepage generates a bunch of checkboxes to generate a searchquery for some specific values.

```
<div id="searchbar">
  {% for foo in bar %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="foovar" value={{foo.name}}{%if foo.name in p %}checked=checked{%endif%}>{{foo.name}}<br>
  {%endfor%}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
<div id="searchresult">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

The value 'bar' is the parameter passed to the template containing all specific values:

```
 return render_to_response('testlink/foobar.html',{'bar':strings_from_database})
```

Now, upon submitting the values, they are passed to my view, some magic happens, and the result is passed via

```
 return render(request,'extend/extend.html',{'result':result,'p':queried_values})
```

result is the result, p contains the queried values (to keep the checkboxes checked after submitting).

```
 {% extends "testlink/foobar.html" %}
 {% block content %}
 <b>results:</b>  <br>
 {% for result in result %}
     {{result.someattribute}}<br>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Now, my problem: The checkboxes disappear, probably as the 'for foo in bar' loop is executed again. Is there a way to prevent that from happening, without to hardcode the checkboxes into my template? This would work (i did it with a few checkboxes, but doing this with too many searchvalues is no fun. Also i would like to avoid additional database hits and passing the parameters again.

Comment: Are you using a django `Form`?

Comment: no, all html is done in separate .html files.

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/)? It would make it very simple to output the fields in your template since that is what it was designed to do.

Comment: i am new to django, and it quite much to deal with, so i tried to find the easiest way... thinking not handle too much new information would make it easier. but if it does not, i will look into it. for now, i have to deal with the sql stuff, which also is no fun :/... but thanks for your input!

Comment: Definitely does not help to do it your own way first. Best bet is to try django's way, if it doesn't work for you, do it your way. Eventually you will come back and look at what django can do and maybe find a better way to do things. As for the sql... Django's ORM is very powerful and very little sql is actually needed. You may need to do raw queries in the future, but if you are using Django, you should make use of it's features...

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should really work your way through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/), it covers lots of topics and will get you started off pretty well.

Comment: Oh i did, helped a lot for the basic stuff. Some probleme i have are not covered there u fortunately, but the django documentations and examles are very useful in general!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above, using forms is almost always a better idea. But in response to your problem, if you are not passing the `bar` variable to the template, the loop that parses the checkboxes will not be executed. You would need to add `bar` to the context for `extend.html`:

```
return render(request,'extend/extend.html',
    {'result':result,'p':queried_values, 'bar':strings_from_database})
```

Are you not doing this just to prevent hitting the DB twice? Has it proven a very expensive query to run?

Apart from setting up caching, you can always pass ALL the checkboxes "names" along with the form. You can add hidden inputs, like so:

```
{% for foo in bar %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="foovar" value="{{foo.name}}" {%if foo.name in p %}checked="checked"{%endif%}>{{foo.name}}<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="foovar_all" value="{{foo.name}}" />
{%endfor%}
```

Then you need to collect the values with something like:

```
bar = request.POST.getlist('foovar_all')
```

But you would need to rethink your code so the `bar` variables hold just the names of those objects in both views, it looks like it is a list of objects currently. Again, is it really necessary to avoid that query?

Comment: i was intentionally leaving this part away, hoping the already generated checkboxes remain unaltered. The additionally request will probably be no problem, especially as i have different problems with my sql queries :( ... to use the pizza-toppings many-to-many-field example: i want to find all pizzas that use topping T1, T2, T3 and T4 (they can have more, but must have these toppings). i did it with a self created query before (using joins and subselects, which was able to handle many toppings), but i want to do it the django-way. yet, i could not figure out how to do it

Comment: isnt the hidden checkbox redundant to the normal one i already use? the name of every checkbox is the same, so i already use bar = request.GET.getlist('foovar'). may i failed to make clear that it is the same on every checkbox, my aplogies. however, i start looking into Form, and will later have a look at this query i still struggle with.

Comment: @user1451340 if I understand correctly, "bar" should hold all of the checkboxes, not only the selected ones. If you do not add the hidden input, you will only get the selected ones. Unchecked checkboxes are NOT submitted. Regarding your doubts about querying, I am sure you will receive quick help if you post a question with your current attempt and explaining what you are trying to get.

Comment: yes, i already figured out how to keep checked checkboxes checked after submitting, passing the additional data. initially i tried to avoid that, but this seems not to be possible the way i tried to go. i will post my query question as soon as i am back to the point where bad performance gets in my way, for now i have to look into the django form module, and how to work with it. thanks for your help! :)